# passing in forms into HTML page django

Tags: python, django

I am currently learning Django and I was wondering if I am understanding all of this correctly. In my views.py, i created an args dictionary with `args={}`. I passed in 2 values into `args` with `args.update(csrf(request))` and `args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()`. I was wondering in the line `return render(request, 'register.html', args)`, am I passing in an empty form from `args['form']` into the HTML page where it is labeled `{{form}}`?

my register.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form action = '/accounts/register/' method = 'POST'>{% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type = 'submit' value = "Register" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

my views.py:

```
def register_user(request):
    # second time around
    if request.method == 'POST':        # look into request.method and see if it has POST
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)     # pass through the values in the POST to the custom form to create form object
        if form.is_valid():             # check if information if correct
            form.save()                 # if correct, save form, and that will save the registration information for the new user
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')

    # first time around
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm() # BLANK user creation form with no information
    return render(request, 'register.html', args)       # passes 'form' from args into the html page
```

Comment: have you tried `{{ form.as_p }}` ?

Comment: no i have not! what does this do exactly?

Comment: it will print out the form fields

Comment: all I see is that it spaced everything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> am I passing in an empty form from `args['form']` into the HTML page where it is labeled `{{form}}`

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

See this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template). and try that:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form action = '/accounts/register/' method = 'POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type = 'submit' value = "Register" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, args is set to a instance of your form MyRegistrationForm as form.

This is beyond what you have asked but I have recently used. if you want to customise your HTML further for the form you can use a for loop to loop through your form displaying labels and input fields corresponding to your model.

example below - using styled twitter bootstrap

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/accounts/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="id_{{ field.name }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ field }}
     </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

field.label - label

field - input field

Comment: Ill give it a shot thank you! took a bit for me to figure how this all worked out! thank you for the help! much appreciated!